# What is Kinect + Linux being used for?

Tags: linux, kinect

An [article](https://hackaday.com/2018/02/18/rejecting-microsofts-phaseout-of-the-kinect/) on Hackaday piqued my curiosity, and I see Kinect + Linux questions being asked here (mostly about configuration), so I'll venture this question:

It is clear to me that Kinect *can* be used together with Linux on a "regular pc" -- but I can't help wondering *why*, that is, what might you actually use this for?

I don't suppose people *really* like the human/computer interface presented in movies such as "Minority Report" -- surely, nobody is *actually* doing text editing, coding, or business data processing by "hand-waving". So besides just games & exercises, **what are examples of actual, real-world, *useful* (ie. 'professional') applications of such a setup?**

For instance, can it be used for 3D scanning of real-world objects to obtain digital models? What sort of accuracy would such a scan yield?

Comment: The only thing i can think as a limit to what can be done is your imagination.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kinect can be used for a wide variety of useful applications. I'm not sure if you are asking specifically about Linux or if Windows ("regular PC") is acceptable, but I'll provide you with some examples that come to mind.

For Linux specifically, it is likely that applications on Linux are using the sensor's raw sensor data only, rather the skeletal tracking feature. Many Kinect applications are on Windows because Microsoft's Kinect SDK is available only on Windows, and it provides the best skeletal tracking accuracy to-date.

You are right that the Kinect is rarely used where a keyboard & mouse would be faster and more accurate, but note that it is potentially relevant for accessibility.

And yes, it can be used for 3D scanning of real-world objects. I'm not sure about the exact accuracy, but I think it is acceptable for many applications. The main benefits are its low cost and speed.

For examples of 3D scanning, check out:

- [KinectFusion](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/kinectfusion-project-page/), a Microsoft Research project
- [Occipital](https://occipital.com/) Structure sensor for 3D scanning. (This is not the Kinect sensor, but provides an example application for 3D scanning. The company has a Kinect-related history as well.)
- [Styku](https://www.styku.com/) - 3D body scanning for clothes fitting

Aside from 3D scanning, here are some other examples of applications:

- [Atlas5D](http://www.atlas5d.com/) - at-home patient monitoring
- [GestSure](https://www.gestsure.com/) - 'Minority Report' interface for surgical rooms
- [Jintronix](http://www.jintronix.com/) - games, exercises, assessments for physical therapy

There are many depth sensors like the Kinect3D on the market. The latest notable application would be iPhone X's depth sensor and FaceID. Many companies in the space are working actively in FaceID now, which would also be useful on Linux. Check out Microsoft's Window Hello biometric facial ID system - see Microsoft's [official website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect):

> Manufacturing of the Kinect sensor and adapter has been discontinued,
>   but the Kinect technology continues to live on in products like the
>   HoloLens, Cortana voice assistant, the Windows Hello biometric facial
>   ID system, and a context-aware user interface.

Kinect has applications in the robotics community as well, though I don't know the specifics. I assume many in robotics community use Linux when working with the Kinect. The depth and color cameras can be used to provide vision and the microphone array for audio input.

Generally, the Kinect had a big impact when it was released not just because of its technology but also because of its low price point, even if it's not the most accurate for every application. As this technology improves, I hope many other applications will emerge and become mainstream.

EDIT: also, check out this [Hacker News discussion: "Microsoft Has Stopped Manufacturing The Kinect"](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15550735)